# Why does this inequality hold for $|y|\geq 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

My lecture notes use this inequality for a complex $z=x+iy$ with $|y|\geq 1$ $$|\cot(z)| \leq \frac{1+\exp(-2|y|)}{1-\exp(-2|y|)}.$$
How can I show it?

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
|\cot(z)| &= \left| i\frac{1+e^{2 y}e^{-2xi}}{1-e^{2 y}e^{-2xi}} \right|\\
& \leq  \frac{1+\left|e^{2 y}e^{-2xi}\right|}{\left|1-\left|e^{2 y}e^{-2xi} \right|\right|}\\
& =  \frac{1+e^{2 y}}{\left|1-e^{2 y}\right|}\\
& = \hspace{0.5em} ?
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $y < 0$, then you just have one more step to do from where you left off (if $y < 0$, $1 - e^{2y} > 0$)

If $y > 0$, then as Oussama suggested, multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{-2y}$ to finish off.

Answer (score 0):

The cotangent is an odd function that takes real values over real paramaters, hence, by symmetry, it is enough to show that
$$ \left|\cot(x+iy)\right| \leq \frac{1+e^{-2y}}{1-e^{-2y}}=\coth(y)\tag{1}$$
holds for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y\geq 1$, or:
$$\cos(x+iy)\cos(x-iy) \leq \coth(y)^2\sin(x+iy)\sin(x-iy) \tag{2}$$
or:
$$ \frac{\cosh(2y)-\cos(2x)}{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)} \leq \coth(y)^2\tag{3} $$
$$ \frac{2\cosh^2(y)-(1+\cos(2x))}{2\sinh^2(y)+(1+\cos(2x))} \leq \frac{\cosh(y)^2}{\sinh(y)^2}\tag{4} $$
but the last inequality is trivial:
$$ \frac{2\cosh^2(y)-(1+\cos(2x))}{2\sinh^2(y)+(1+\cos(2x))} \leq \frac{2\cosh^2(y)}{2\sinh^2(y)+(1+\cos(2x))}\leq \frac{\cosh(y)^2}{\sinh(y)^2}.\tag{5} $$